# Is this a bug in group_by and lead/lag?

Tags: r, dplyr

Example:

```
library(dplyr) # version 0.4.3

df <- 
    data.frame(hour = 0:11, minutes = runif(12, 0, 59), count = rpois(12, 3)) %>%
    arrange(hour, minutes)

df %>%
    group_by(hour) %>%
    mutate(diff = count - lag(count, default = max(count)))
```

raises an error:

```
Error: expecting a single value
```

The following raises a different error:

```
> df %>%
+     group_by(hour) %>%
+     mutate(diff = count - lag(count, default = count))
Error: not compatible with requested type
```

I feel like both should work and the answer should be data frame containing a `diff` column of zeros. This is because there is only one row per group, and I am expecting the default non-existent row value to be the maximum count in that group.

Comment: Not having a problem with `dplyr_0.5.0`

Comment: Thanks, that must be it.

Comment: Ok, installing to version 0.5.0 fixed the first problem, but not the second.

Comment: The default can take a single value, while `count` is a column, try `count[1]`.  Anyway, we are replacing only a single NA

Comment: but why is count not equal to count[1]? is it because one the first is a data.frame column and the second is not?

Comment: Because `count` is a column having elements of length >1.  I think `lag` expects a single value for `default`

Comment: but once it is in group_by there is only one element in `count` for each group?

Comment: but `count` is still a column

Comment: Thanks! So, specifically, the problem is that `count` is a  dataframe column when a single value was expected?

Comment: The error suggests there is a problem in the `type`.  So I am guessing that is still a `data.frame`.  BTW, I am using `0.5.0`, this could change in the newer version (development version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error seems to be version specific, but the second one we can remove by selecting the `first` observation of 'count' or `last` one.

```
df %>%
   group_by(hour) %>%
   mutate(diff = count - lag(count, default = first(count)))
```